# iOS Swift Label Frame Height Not Updating Correctly

Tags: ios, swift, label, height, frame

I have a Label whose text changes each time the user clicks a Button.  However, the **Label.frame.height value does not update immediately** even though the Label content has changed.  The function to change the Label is called in multiple places, yet the height ONLY updates just inside the @IBAction block, and its value lags one click cycle.  My code is as follows:

```
func changeLabelText() {
//Here I have an algorithm (not shown) that generates myMutableString 
Label.attributedText = myMutableString  //Label is updated.
}


@IBAction func changeLabelButton(sender: UIButton) {
print("1. Height = ", Label.frame.height) //Height updates here, but it's the old value.  
changeLabelText()  //Label is updated.
print("2. Height = ", Label.frame.height) //Returns same height as Line 1!!
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
print("3. Height = ", Label.frame.height) //Initially, height is 21.0 when ViewController first loads.
changeLabelText() //Label is updated.
print("4. Height = ", Label.frame.height) //Returns height = 21.0, even though simulator shows Label updated!!
}
```

In summary, this is what's happening:

1. User clicks Button, Label displays new text, but frame.height is unchanged.
2. User clicks Button again, Label text changes again, frame.height updates this time, but updates to the old value it should've had on Step 1.

I'm relatively new to Swift, and any help with this is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call these methods immediately after changing the text

```
label.setNeedsLayout()
label.layoutIfNeeded()
```

this will give you the correct frame.

Comment: .layoutIfNeeded() appears to have solved my problems. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

When iOS animates the resize, it actually changes the display layer first, and then the actual frame of the object (or roughly along those lines).

<s>Try querying `Label.layer.frame.height`</s>

Try calling `Label.sizeToFit()` to force the redraw before you get to the second `print` call.

Alternatively, you can wait a few ticks, until iOS has done it itself:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 10000000), dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    print("2. Height = ", self.Label.frame.height) //Returns the correct height
})
```

Comment: Thanks pff.  But the layer.frame.height value I get is always the same as the frame.height.  All I really wanted to do is to get the height of the text in the label.  But .frame.height returns old values.

Comment: Try calling `Label.sizeToFit()` at the end of your `changeLabelText()` function to force the redraw of the bounds before your second `print` call happens.

Comment: Basically what's happening is, iOS is waiting until it has time to resize the label. Because it needs to hurry up and do other more important things, like call your second `print` function. If you tell it it's important to go ahead and resize, it will do that first.

Comment: pfj... to make a long story short, sizeToFit() worked almost perfectly - except that (for some reason) the very first label update resulted in the height being adjusted to fit text per landscape orientation (although i was in portrait).  The label.layoutIfNeeded() method, below, seems to have fixed everything.  I really appreciate your help and will keep that nifty "sizeToFit" method in my back pocket for future use.